# In which port do I plugin my Microlab k380 headphone to be able to both talk and listen to?

Tags: headphones

I've bought a Microlab k380 headphone recently. But I am not been able to use it for talking over Skype. I don't know which port should I plugin my headphone to be able to talk. 
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What type of connector does it have for the stereo and microphone cable?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a USB headset so you need a combined headphone/microphone socket.

Alternatively, you can get adaptors to split a combined jack plug into separate ones.